# How to solve the contradiction between Expected all tensors to be on the same device and can’t convert CUDA tensor to numpy

Tags: numpy, pytorch, multi-gpu

I'm trying yolov3 with multi GPUs...

```
    def evaluate(self):
        self.models.eval()

        labels = []
        sample_metrics = []  # List of tuples (TP, confs, pred)
        for batch_i, (_, imgs, targets) in enumerate(tqdm.tqdm(self.valid_dataloader, desc="Detecting objects")):
            # Extract labels
            labels += targets[:, 1].tolist()
            # Rescale target
            targets[:, 2:] = xywh2xyxy(targets[:, 2:])
            targets[:, 2:] *= self.img_size

            #targets = targets.cuda()

            #imgs = Variable(imgs.type(Tensor), requires_grad=False)

            imgs = imgs.cuda()

            with torch.no_grad():
                outputs = self.models(imgs)
                outputs = non_max_suppression(outputs, conf_thres=self.conf_thres, nms_thres=self.nms_thres)

            sample_metrics += get_batch_statistics(outputs, targets, iou_threshold=self.iou_thres)

        # Concatenate sample statistics
        true_positives, pred_scores, pred_labels = [np.concatenate(x, 0) for x in list(zip(*sample_metrics))]
        precision, recall, AP, f1, ap_class = ap_per_class(true_positives, pred_scores, pred_labels, labels)

        return precision, recall, AP, f1, ap_class
```

If I use those two commented lines, I will face

> ```
> TypeError: can’t convert CUDA tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first
> ```

But if I don't, I will face

> ```
> RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!
> ```

How to solve?

Trace:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:/Code/DeblurGANv2-master/train.py", line 415, in <module>
        trainer.train()
    File "D:/Code/DeblurGANv2-master/train.py", line 253, in train
        self._run_epoch(epoch)
    File "D:/Code/DeblurGANv2-master/train.py", line 287, in _run_epoch
        loss_detect = self.calculate()
    File "D:/Code/DeblurGANv2-master/train.py", line 224, in calculate
        precision, recall, AP, f1, ap_class = self.evaluate()
    File "D:/Code/DeblurGANv2-master/train.py", line 160, in evaluate
        sample_metrics += get_batch_statistics(outputs, targets, 
    iou_threshold=self.iou_thres)
    File "D:\Code\DeblurGANv2-master\util\utils.py", line 172, in 
    get_batch_statistics
        if pred_label not in target_labels:
    File "D:\soft\Anaconda3\envs\DeblurGANv2-master\lib\site- 
    packages\torch\tensor.py", line 659, in __contains__
        return (element == self).any().item()  # type: ignore[union-attr]
    File "D:\soft\Anaconda3\envs\DeblurGANv2-master\lib\site- 
   packages\torch\tensor.py", line 27, in wrapped
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found 
    at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!
```

I assume the problem is about the sample_metrics, no matter put this tensor on GPU or CPU, there are always problems...

Comment: we need to see the trace of the errors - what line exactly produced them.

Comment: Please don't tag this as a CUDA programming question, because it isn't one.

Comment: what is you comment just `imgs = Variable(imgs.type(Tensor), requires_grad=False)` and leave `imgs = imgs.cuda()` and `targets = targets.cuda()` uncommented?